# How to extract a compressed tar using cpio to a particular directory location

Tags: find, tar, gzip, cpio

I created the compressed tar file using the below command.

```
find /app/jboss -not -name "*.err" -not -name "*.log" | cpio -o | gzip >/app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz
```

I got the compressed file here

```
[user1@myhost test]$ ls -ltr /app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user1 mygrp 363997224 Aug 18 16:08 /app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz
```

I want to extract the `/app/jboss` directory under `/app/patchbkp/test` so i get `/app/patchbkp/test/app/jboss/.......`; thus i try the below command.

```
cd /app/patchbkp/test/
zcat /app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz | cpio -i
```

But this does not generate any files under `/app/patchbkp/test`

I get permission denied error when i try `gunzip /app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz`

Can you please guide me as to how can I extract the tar compressed `/app/jboss` under `/app/patchbkp/test` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command creates a compressed `cpio`-format archive with absolute filenames. This means that when you extract the files, they will be placed in those absolute places

Note that `cpio -o` writes a `cpio`-format archive, not a `tar`-format one. You should use `cpio -o -H tar` for a `tar`-format file.

Your extract command will work, but only by writing the files to the absolute locations on the filesystem. You can see what would happen by first listing the file with the `-t` flag

```
zcat /app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz | cpio -it
```

I would instead recommend these variants of your commands

```
( cd / && find app/jboss -not -name "*.err" -not -name "*.log" | cpio -o -H tar ) | gzip >/app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz
```

or even use GNU `tar` directly if you have it

```
tar -C / -f /app/patchbkp/test/REDHAT_jboss-eap-7.2_18-Aug-2020.tar.gz -cv --exclude '*.log' --exclude '*.err' app/jboss
```

Comment: `find` does not support a primary called `-not`.

Comment: @schily it's a [GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dnot). The OP used it, so I continued with their original command as a starting point